# PHP 5.5 magic quotes?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get PHP to stop storing backslashes in the database (I'm using `PHP-PDO`).

I'm using PHP 5.5 though, where apparently there is no magic quotes setting, yet it is still happening.

What am I missing here?

Comment: when you  `print_r($_POST)` do you see `\` in them then?

Comment: I do yes. I tried with "hello" and it puts `\"hello\"`

Comment: Well, then, I have no idea. There should be no way that's possible in PHP 5.5 given the directive is completely gone. That being said, I would try re-installing php.

Comment: You're either not running PHP/5.5 or you have some PHP code that's adding them. Please test in a simple ad-hoc script. You can also search for `addslashes` or `addcslahes` in your bode-base.

Comment: I checked and it's definitely 5.5.10, in an adhoc script it does it. Perhaps its something Amazon put into their Amazon Linux AMI with this PHP version or something... not sure.

Comment: What database are you using?  And is there a framework involved here?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Pantheon, even though the dashboard says its using PHP 5.5. I used the code here to strip them out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php .

Remember to remove the conditional that calls `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` since that always returns false in 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` function to check the magic quotes.
if function returns true then by using `stripslashes()` function to stop storing backslashes in the database.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $_REQUEST['input'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['input']);
}
```

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc` changelog: "PHP 5.4 = Always returns FALSE because the magic quotes feature was removed from PHP".

For anyone having this issue with `json_encode()`, `json_decode()` automatically unescapes quotes put in by `json_encode()` in PHP 5.5